# Java math isnt making sense

Tags: java, double

OK so this is a problem in a larger piece of code which does'nt seem to make sense. below is the code which is the problem... It prints `Ratio = 0.0` the console when launched it should be equal to ~0,348.

```
public class MathTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double ratio = 29511 / 84812;
        System.out.println("Ratio = "+ ratio);

    }

}
```

Edit:

What if the code is this:

```
public class MathTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int int1 = 7;
        int int2 = 13;
        double double1 = int1/int2;
        System.out.println("double1 = "+ double1);

    }

}
```

It again prints "0.0".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have unwittingly used integer division when you say `29511 / 84812`, which in Java, loses the decimal points.  Use `double` literals (with `.0` added) instead:

```
double ratio = 29511.0 / 84812.0;
```

Other solutions that work here:

- Cast one of them to a `double`: `(double) 29511 / 84812`
- Use 'D' as another way to indicate a Java `double` literal: `29511D / 84812D`

Comment: Or double ratio = 29511D / 84812D;

Comment: What if there are two ints such as

int int1 = 7;
int int2 = 13;
double double1 = int1/int2;
System.out.println("double1 = "+ double1);

Comment: @Mean Correct, that's another way.

Comment: Thanks 6 mins till i can mark sloved :)

Answer (score 3):

You are doing integer division because `29511` and `84812` are ints. The result of the division is 0, and you are saving it as a double so it becomes 0.0.

To fix this, cast one of the operands on the right side of the assignment to a double.

```
double ratio = (double)29511 / 84812;
```

Comment: Thanks this solved the second problem

Answer (score 0):

Replace `double ratio = 29511 / 84812` with `double ratio = 29511.0 / 84812.0`;

Answer (score 0):

It make perfect sense. You are dividing two integers to get an integer.  This means 0 in this case.